# Recall menu within cmd module python

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I am making making a commandline program using python's cmd module. In this program I use numbers in order to determine what feature the user want to use. I have the following issue for feature 6 which is simply printing out the features again but I want to recall the MainMenu class so I don't have to use:

```
def do_6(self, line):
        print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
        print ("1. Feature one")
        print ("2. Feature two")
        print ("3. Feature three")
        print ("4. Feature four")
        print ("5. Feature five")
        print ("6. Print options")
        print ("7. Exit ")
        print (30 * '-')
```

Which is simply just repeating what is in the MainMenu class but is a bit sloppy if you want to change the MainMenu. You are forced to also change feature 6.

MainMenu class:

```
class MainMenu(cmd.Cmd):
    print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
    print ("1. Feature one")
    print ("2. Feature two")
    print ("3. Feature three")
    print ("4. Feature four")
    print ("5. Feature five")
    print ("6. Print options")
    print ("7. Exit ")
    print (30 * '-')
```

I tried doing this:

```
def do_6(self, line):
        MainMenu()
```

or

```
def do_6(self, line):
        MainMenu
```

But this has no effect, how do I recall my MainMenu class properly? My second question is: Let's say I want to recall the MainMenu class everytime a feature has ended or completed, how do I do this?

Comment: Where is do_6 defined? In a class? If so what does that class look like?

Comment: You shouldn't put `print` functions directly in the body of your class. They should be inside a method that's inside the class.

Comment: @heinst do_6 is defined in the MainMenu class. All features are in defined in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainMenu(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        """ Class constructor """

        print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
        print ("1. Feature one")
        print ("2. Feature two")
        print ("3. Feature three")
        print ("4. Feature four")
        print ("5. Feature five")
        print ("6. Print options")
        print ("7. Exit ")
        print (30 * '-')
```

You need to understand how class works. Classes have members, methods and many other features. As in all the languages, you need to define this fields. For example, here is a method with a constructor, a field and a method :

```
class Example:

    field = "foo"

    def __init__(self, ivar_value):
        self.instance_var = ivar_value

    def print_me(self):
        print("Field : ", self.field)
        print("Var   : ", self.instance_var)
```

Classes are only defined once. And when you tryied to run the `MainMenu()` with your way to do it, it would work only one time because the second time, the class MainMenu was already defined.

Comment: I do understand the point you are trying to make I think. You are saying I should make the print lines in a method which I can recall and not the class itself which can only be called once right?

Comment: Yes that's it. Just notice it could be another method that `__init__` (that's probably a better way to do), and then you run your method as following : `MainMenu().my_method()`

Comment: I made a method of it by using: 'def start(self): Print stuff'  and I can finally recall it in def do_6 by using: 'MainMenu().start()' but its almost what I am looking for. Previously the MainMenu's print stuff would instantly get printed when I run the program but not anymore because I made a method of it how do I fix this?